# How to submit a form then on completion call a jquery function without redirecting MVC/C#/Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I have a problem, Im trying to display a message on the same page  after the form has been submitted, but my result is always false because my action in my controller gets called twice, when I click on the submit button, The first time around my action is called the data is passed through to the action with the correct info and is saved to the db, the second time around every parameter is null thus return false.

I want a way to submit only once and return the appropriate Json result in the same page without redirecting, I hope someone can help me with this, here is my code:

I tried:

```
function PdfHeaderAndFooterManager() {
 $('#submitPdf').ajaxSubmit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Dashboard/PdfHeaderAndFooterManager",
            dataType: "json",
            type:"POST",
            data: {headerImage: headerImage, footerImage: footerImage},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    alert(data.message);
                    $('#resultMessage').text(data.message).css("color", "RED");
                }
                else {
                    alert(data.message);
                    $('#resultMessage').text(data.message).css("color", "RED");
                }
            }

        });
       e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

My view some code removed for simplicity

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PdfHeaderAndFooterManager", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "formPdfImages" }))
 div id="resultMessage"></div>
}

public ActionResult PdfHeaderAndFooterManager(HttpPostedFileBase headerImage, HttpPostedFileBase footerImage)
    {

       //some code to declare variables


        if (headerImage != null)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(headerImage.ContentType))
            {
                headerImageContentType = imageHelper.IsValidImageType(headerImage.ContentType);

                if (headerImageContentType)
                {
                    resizedHeaderImage = imageHelper.ResizeImage(headerImage.InputStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { success = false, message = "Please Upload an image* file less than 2GB." });
                }
            }
        }
        if (footerImage != null)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(footerImage.ContentType))
            {
                footerImageContentType = imageHelper.IsValidImageType(footerImage.ContentType);
                if (footerImageContentType)
                {   
                    resizedFooterImage = imageHelper.ResizeImage(footerImage.InputStream);
                }
                else
                {

                    return Json(new { success = false, message = "Please Upload an image* file less than 2GB." });
                }
            }
        }
        if (P24DataPrincipal.CurrentIdentity != null)
        {
            if (resizedHeaderImage != null || resizedFooterImage != null)
            {
              //add to DB code
                return Json(new { success = true, message = "Image(s) Uploaded Successfully." });

            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new {success = false, message = "Upload atleast 1 image file." });

            }

        }

        return Json("someview");

    }
```

and above is my action the most important parts are the "return" keywords I just want to see that in my view even when the result is true not only when the result is false and this action should be only called once and not redirect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an `<input type="submit" />`?  If so, change it to a button and wire it up in your jQuery `ready` so that it hits your function:

```
$.ready(function(){
    $("#submitButtonId").click(function() {
        //put your ajax stuff here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first function actually looks close to being correct. A few small tweaks would look as per below.

Does the following work?

```
$(function() {
    $('#formPdfImages').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        $.post("@(Url.Action("PdfHeaderAndFooterManager", "Dashboard"))", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $("#resultMessage").text(data.success);
            } else {
                $("resultMessage").text(data.success);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I get an error saying  event.preventDefault();
 is not a function :(

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ was added in version 1. Are you in fact using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and you can't make Ajax call using **submit** with this,

for ajax call you will have to use: `@using (Ajax.BeginForm())`,

But you need to upload an image, so you must have to use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PdfHeaderAndFooterManager", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "formPdfImages" }))
```

So, Ajax call is not possible. For displaying messages on the same page, use another alternative, that may be:

```
public ActionResult PdfHeaderAndFooterManager(HttpPostedFileBase headerImage, HttpPostedFileBase footerImage)
    {

   //some code to declare variables


    if (headerImage != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(headerImage.ContentType))
        {
            headerImageContentType = imageHelper.IsValidImageType(headerImage.ContentType);

            if (headerImageContentType)
            {
                resizedHeaderImage = imageHelper.ResizeImage(headerImage.InputStream);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ReturnMessage="<span style='color:red'> Please Upload an image* file less than 2GB.</span>";
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
    if (footerImage != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(footerImage.ContentType))
        {
            footerImageContentType = imageHelper.IsValidImageType(footerImage.ContentType);
            if (footerImageContentType)
            {   
                resizedFooterImage = imageHelper.ResizeImage(footerImage.InputStream);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ReturnMessage="<span style='color:red'>Please Upload an image* file less than 2GB.</span>";
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
    if (P24DataPrincipal.CurrentIdentity != null)
    {
        if (resizedHeaderImage != null || resizedFooterImage != null)
        {
          //add to DB code
                ViewBag.ReturnMessage="<span style='color:green'>Image(s) Uploaded Successfully.</span>";
                return View();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnMessage="<span style='color:red'>Upload atleast 1 image file.</span>";
            return View();
        }

    }
```

In View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PdfHeaderAndFooterManager", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "formPdfImages" })){
 <div id="resultMessage">
    @ViewBag.ReturnMessage
</div>
    }
```